# Adding card after clicking on button

Tags: android, user-interface, fragment

I'd like to add new card to the view after clicking on button. It's simple but I can't imagine how to do that.
I'd like to use CardView and Fragment.

Could you give me a example or any tutorial for designing GUI in Android? I was looking for something hardly, but nothing interesting I found.

Comment: Here is [Guide using RecyclerView for CardView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Comment: This is a tutorial I made on creating Card like lists using Cardview: http://www.exoguru.com/android/ui/cardview/custom-android-list.html

Comment: I have not talked about how you can add cards using a button in that tutorial but i think i found something related to it after digging through this: https://github.com/chiuki/android-recyclerview Even though that app is based on grids its still using recyclerview so it should work with cards aswell :D

Comment: Thanks for yours comments, those are so good examples :)